# Regex - Shortening an expression

Tags: regex

I'm currently trying to get data out of HTML-Code in java. I have this example:

```
<div class="whenm">21 hours from now<span style="font-weight: bold; color: #D12121">  LDLC = EnvyUs  </span>
```

Now i want to get the data "LDLC = EnvyUS" as a string in java, but the program always adds the last whitespaces before `</span>` to the string as well and I can't figure out, how to solve it.
Current expression:

```
.*<span style="font-weight: bold; color: #D12121">\s*(.+)\s*<\/span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's happening because the "+"-operator per se is greedy. So it matches as much as he can. Because of the . it also matches the whitespaces. By adding a ? after the + you make it non-greedy.

Try this:

```
.*<span style="font-weight: bold; color: #D12121">\s*(.+?)\s*<\/span>
```

Comment: I would recommend using `\S+` or `[^\s]+` instead of `.+?`.

Comment: @Lindrian - that's no correct. The OP asked for a regex which matches "LDLC = EnvyUS". The expected match contains spaces, so you can't replace .+? with \S+ or [^\s]+

Comment: @netblognet: You're right, I see my mistake now. This is poor regex design though as you're relying heavily on the engine to backtrack until it finds a match. I personally don't like seeing such expressions in my code.